# How to customize 3D plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d, tikz-3dplot

In this 3d plot of the Mexican hat potential, how can I get the back to extend further upward than the front (as poorly indicated by the blue lines) so as not to obstruct the circle of minima quite so much?
[image]

```
\documentclass[svgnames]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
    
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            axis lines=center,
            axis equal,
            domain=0:360,
            y domain=0:1.25,
            y axis line style=stealth-,
            y label style={at={(0.325,0.15)}},
            xmax=1.75,ymax=1.5,zmax=1.5,
            xlabel = $\varphi_1$,
            ylabel=$\varphi_2$,
            zlabel=$U_k(\rho)$,
            ticks=none,
        ]
        
        \addplot3 [surf,shader=flat,draw=black,fill=white,z buffer=sort] ({sin(x)*y}, {cos(x)*y}, {(y^2-1)^2});
        \end{axis}
        \fill[DarkBlue] (3.05,3.4) circle (0.1) coordinate (center);
        \fill[DarkRed] (4.7,2) circle (0.1) coordinate (minimum);
        \draw[LightGray,line width=0.8,shorten <=5,shorten >=5] (center) edge[out=-15,in=150,->] (minimum);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the angles from which you see the plot with the `view={phi}{theta}` option.
Moreover, you should define the coordinates of `(center)` and `(minimum)` inside the axis environment, and then draw them outside.

```
\documentclass[svgnames]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            axis lines=center,
            axis equal,
            domain=0:360,
            y domain=0:1.25,
            y axis line style=stealth-,
            y label style={at={(0.325,0.15)}},
            xmax=1.75,ymax=1.5,zmax=1.5,
            xlabel = $\varphi_1$,
            ylabel=$\varphi_2$,
            zlabel=$U_k(\rho)$,
            ticks=none,
            view={30}{35}
        ]

            \addplot3 [surf,shader=flat,draw=black,fill=white,z buffer=sort] ({sin(x)*y}, {cos(x)*y}, {(y^2-1)^2});
            \coordinate (center) at (axis cs:0,0,1);
            \coordinate (minimum) at (axis cs:{cos(30)},{sin(30)},0);
        \end{axis}
        \fill[DarkBlue] (center) circle (0.1);
        \fill[DarkRed] (minimum) circle (0.1);
        \draw[LightGray,line width=0.8,shorten <=5,shorten >=5] (center) edge[out=-15,in=150,->] (minimum);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]